# update function not effecting te database(RAILS )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to delete an BSON id . It deletes the element from the object's array but does not effects the database. Can you please tell me what is it that I am doing wrong. Thanks

```
  def delete_bookmark
    request_to_be_deleted = params[:d]
    l = request_to_be_deleted.split("'")
    request_to_be_deleted = l[1]
    request_bookmarks = params[:d1]
    l = request_bookmarks.split("'")
    request_bookmarks = l[1]
    b = Bookmark.where(request_id: request_bookmarks).first()
    b1 = b
    req = Request.find(request_to_be_deleted)
    b1[:corsponding_requests].delete(req[:_id])

    b1.update(Hash['corsponding_requests' , b1[:corsponding_requests]])
    session[:request_bookmarks] = request_bookmarks
    asd
    render :action => "bookmark"
  end
```

Bookmark Model

```
include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :user_id, type: Mongoid
  field :request_id, type: Mongoid
  field :corsponding_requests, type: Array

  validates_presence_of :user_id , :request_id

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :request
```

Comment: It's only wild guess, but maybe validation fails?

Comment: validation does not fails. I am deleting it somewhere else to and it's being deleted. I had this problem at that point too but then I defined the relation. I just can't understand that why isn't it deleting it here

Comment: what is `corsponding_requests`? association or a field ? Show your `Bookmark` model

Comment: update executes successfully only when all relevant validations passes...please check whether you are trying to save valid values and model.errors is empty or model.validate method is nil

Comment: @Milind Bookmark.error returns this `#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007f51f871ba78 @base=#<Bookmark _id: 5533bf1e6761720ce3350000, created_at: 2015-04-19 14:43:42 UTC, updated_at: 2015-04-19 14:43:53 UTC, user_id: BSON::ObjectId('553360746761720ce32a0000'), request_id: BSON::ObjectId('5533bf0b6761720ce3340000'), corsponding_requests: []>, @messages={}>` and model.validate returns true

Comment: @lx00st it's a field. I have added the details of bookmark model

Comment: @Milind I am passing all the validation in the validation it requires a user_id and request_id and I am passing a whole object and then I passed a hash so that if it was skipping something I would excitability put in it but it;s still not updating the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't delete the object in the other mongo collection because mongoid has no idea that's what you want to do - as far as it's concerned you've just got an array of ids

If you want mongoid to make that link for you then you need to setup a  [relation](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html) - what you have there looks like a one-sides n-n relation

Comment: Thanks alot your solution helped. Can you tell how do I make a self relation like a request has many favorite request